# Error on dataprofile import action

Tags: magento-1.9, dataflow

I've setup a dataprofile for importing stock data into the webshop. File has approximately 2100 products that need to be updated. Once I start the import after a few seconds the following screen appears:

[image]

In this case I already tried a reduced amount of products. I had it going at around 900 products but that's it. Pasting the HTML appears the dashboard page of the Magento admin.

Does this have to do with memory settings? Why is the HTML generated?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I think magmi Is not great solution , If Hacker got access Of magmi somehow then , chances of hacking will increase. So please dont advice users to use magmi directly

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala hi, hope you are doing good....  you are right, but there is an option to restrict magmi page only to our ip, if we follow that still do you think hackers can catch that ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento Yes Bro you right but when you suggest magmi then also suggest, how to restrict this with ip and `.htpasswd` files so it would be great.

Comment: @Badger best solution is to use `magmi` but make sure you restrict `magmi page` only to your i.p

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I deleted my above comment & wrote another comment as you suggested, you are absolutely right , Thanks for suggestion.....

Answer (score 1):

when you upload csv please be sure you have `''`( single quotation ) in `description` kind of field where chancees of `,` kind of text is more. I think your csv breaks because of this kind of reason ,

please check Your csv has right format and try once with 10-15 products or even Try with 1 product for testing purpose. and find out the possible reason.
This way you can debug this kind error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try in lesser batch of product try with 5-10 first as such one or more products row would be having data that is error prone. Also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978970/magento-importing-product-error) might be helpful for you.